# Jumping and falling force same?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

When someone tries to jump he/she can only jump for a height of few inch and doesnt break his leg which requires a small force but when someone falls from a small building he/she will have much higher impact force so basically why the person that falls (has higher impact force) doesnt break his leg, why someone can withstand so much force but cant even jump for a few inchs. 
For example lets assume a bodybuilder withstands 4000newton when he/she falls.

Comment: I don't follow. Why would you expect the amount of force a bone to withstand to relate to how high someone can jump?

Comment: “The person that falls ... doesn’t break his leg.” Why do you think that?

Comment: A bone can support a high load when it is applied gently in increments, but a small sharp shock will break the same bone...

Comment: Do you mean to ask why our legs are strong enough to withstand large forces when we can only jump a few inches?

Comment: Yep, sorry about that my english is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking if we can fall, say, 10 feet and not break a leg, why can we not jump 10 feet. Our muscles are used for jumping, and our bones can normally, if in good health, withstand more pressure than our muscles can deliver, otherwise we could break a leg climbing stairs quickly.