# Jumping vs hitting the ground

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

Whats the difference between jumping and hitting (kicking) the ground, in both situations the normal force has the same  direction, so why when we hit the ground the ground wont push us back, according to f=ma, When we hit the ground there is more force than when we jump also both normal forces have the same direction but still earth doesnt push us back.

Comment: You should look at : https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/489809/207455

Comment: Why do you think the ground is not "pushing back"?

Comment: When you jump you move your entire body, but when you hit the ground your body doesnt move. Idk.

Comment: So, jump up and then land with your legs straight and locked. See what you think then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ground does push you back when you hit the ground. Try it. Swing your fist at the ground and you'll see it recoil.

Of course you won't experience as large a recoil as when you jump on the ground, but that's because you exert a much larger force when you jump (it's your entire body mass after all).

Comment: Then why my entire body doesnt move when i hit the ground, but when i jump it does

Comment: Because only the part of your body that's hitting the ground is in contact with it.

Comment: When i jump both my legs are in contact with the ground, when i hit the ground both of my legs are hitting the ground, idont see any difference.

Comment: When you hit the ground after jumping, you have speed and momentum. The earth then pushed back on you, but just exactly that much to reduce your speed back to zero. (very simplified)

Comment: @Zheer when you hit the ground only one of your legs is moving relative to the ground.

Comment: When we jump  earth pushes us back thats how we jump, when we hit the ground after that  the earth pushes us back again, why the second time the same thing doesnt happen again, why the earth doesnt force us to jump again.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please clarify.

Comment: @Allure I think the lack of understanding is not us...

Comment: @Zheer I answered that question in my comment

Comment: Thank you, sorry i didnt see that comment.